# Accessing Apple Earbud Clicker Controls in C

Tags: objective-c, c, hid

I wanted to find out if there was any way to have applications access and listen to the Apple Earbud's *Clicker controls* on the newer headphones, much like applications can listen to the IR Receiver for customized Apple Remote functionality. I know that iTunes has this ability (more precisely iTunes Helper) because when I double-click the play/pause clicker iTunes opens. I have looked into trying to access the clicker from HID/IOServices but currently am unable to find an answer, if anyone is able to shed light on this subject it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could hook into this by making your app play audio (silence perhaps?) and then receive the events as "control events" for your "audio player."  You might look at the AV Foundation Framework as a place to start.

Comment: This seems like a good start, I will see if I can't get this working and post the progress here...